# IS NULL doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, null, isnull

I have a table like the one above with the two left columns (Both of them are integer) and I added to this table two more fields:

Table1:

```
Asset_Value    Contract_Value  
-------------------------------
0              NULL             
NULL           200               
0              NULL
```

And the query:

```
Select 
    Asset_Value, Contract_Value,
    Case 
       when Asset_Value is null 
          then 1 
          else 0 
    end As Ind_ForNullA,
    Case 
       when Contract_Value is null
          then 1 
          else 0 
    end As IndForNullC
from 
    table1
```

However, I get strange results:

```
Asset_Value Contract_Value  Ind_ForNullA IndForNullC
----------------------------------------------------
0              NULL              1            1
NULL           200               0            0
0              NULL              0            1
```

Update : Never Mind. Damm comma has been forgetten.

Comment: I can't see the table...

Comment: please post the full query that is giving you the result.

Comment: looking at what you provided, i cannot see why you would get that result or how

Comment: Can't reproduce this - works just fine as you would expect on my SQL Server 2014. There's something missing from your posting - either you're not showing us all the data, or the query has been over-simplified to the point it doesn't do what the actual query is doing ....

Comment: see my update. I forgot a comma :((((

Answer (score 0):

Try with ' ' empty string instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you bothering to define something as NULL--which is appropriate--but, in this case or that one, changing it to one or zero (an attempt at Boolean, I imagine)--which is inappropriate?

What will you do next: decide that, in a third report, you want to have a REAL boolean that displays TRUE or FALSE?

Go with NULL consistently, throughout the entire application, everywhere, or don't.  However, DO NOT MIX AND MATCH PARADIGMS and expect consistent results.  Also, try not to rely upon CASE: there's very, very legitimate reason to depend upon that--especially for something as simplistic as what you're doing.

FYI, the only reason I can conceive why you would want this "indicator" field is so that you can test whether INDICATOR_A = 1.  However, since you can test ASSET IS NULL, why even bother? NEVER introduce extraneous mechanisms when there is no overpowering reason to do so.

Comment: The simple reason for doing this : The client asked for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the function  [ASCII](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms177545.aspx)

> ASCII ( character_expression )

Using this function you can understand what is the really character in the column Asset_Value: for example NULL value must have ASCII code: '00' [Table with character ASCII code](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/null-character-ascii-code-0.html)